# Google Auth: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'presentingViewController must be set.'

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, authentication, google-authentication

I have incorporated Google sign in into my app. It was working well this whole time and then suddenly stopped working, now giving me this error in the debugger:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'presentingViewController must be set.'`

Here is my code for the login view controller (edited to show only necessary code):

```
class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var signInGoogleButton: UIButton!
    
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setUpGoogleButton()
            
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        
    }
    
    
// MARK: - SIGN UP WITH GOOGLE
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
                
        if let err = error {
            print("Failed to log into Google: ", err)
            return
        }
        print("Successfully logged into Google")
        
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        
        // sign user in with Firebase
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            let firstName = user?.user.displayName
            let email = user?.user.email
            let lastName = ""
            let uid = user?.user.uid
            
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
                return
            } else {
                // Successfully logged in
                print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google email: ", email ?? "", "Now add user to Firestore if user is new.")
                
                // check if user already exists
                self.addUserToFirestore(firstName ?? "", lastName, email ?? "", uid ?? "", "Google")
                    }
                })
            }
    
            
        fileprivate func setUpGoogleButton() {
            Utilities.styleLightFilledButton(signInGoogleButton)
            signInGoogleButton!.addTarget(self, action:
                                #selector(handleCustomGoogleSignIn), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
            }
        
        @objc func handleCustomGoogleSignIn() {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
            }

    
// MARK: - Other functions
    
    func addUserToFirestore(_ firstName:String, _ lastName:String, _ email:String, _ uid:String, _ signInMethod:String) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
        // check if user exists in firestore
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document {
               if document.exists {
                let message = "Good news! You already have a Coal account that uses " + email + ".\nPlease sign in to your existing account. Then you will be able to link your " + signInMethod + " profile from your Account Settings page."
                // user exists. send to chats screen.
                print("User already exists. Document data: \(String(describing: document.data()))")
                self.showError("You're already a member!", message)
              } else {
                // user does not exist. create a new user
                 print("Document does not exist. Create new user.")
                
                docRef.setData(["firstname":firstName, "lastname":lastName, "email":email]) { err in
                    if err != nil {
                        // Show error message
                        print("Error saving user data to Firestore")
                    } else {
                        print("New user created in Firestore")
                        self.transitionToConvo()
                    }
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func showError(_ title:String, _ message:String) {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func transitionToConvo() {
        let tabBarC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTabBarController") as! TabBarController
        tabBarC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(tabBarC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Switched to TabBarController")
    }
    
    
} // end
```

Here is the app delegate:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
    
    
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let err = error {
            print("Failed to log into Google: ", err)
            return
        }
        print("Successfully logged into Google")
        
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
                return
            }
            guard let uid = user?.user.uid else { return }
            print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google", uid)
        })
    }
    
    
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
          
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
        
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )
        
        return true
    }
    
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )
        
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }
}
```

The error occurs every time I click the `signInGoogleButton`. Any help is appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Could it be that `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self` is called too late? You do a SignIn inside AppDelegate AND inside `WelcomeViewController`? When it happens inside your AppDelegate, there is no `presentingViewController` set I guess.

Comment: I restarted xcode and it started working like normal. Possibly a glitch?

Comment: Nevermind, still occurring :/. I cannot delete the signIn function inside AppDelegate because it is a required stub for GIDSignInDelegate. What should I do?